# tablesorter how to set dynamic scroller height

Tags: tablesorter

I'm trying to use Tablesorter with the scroller widget. same as this - http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/146/

The widget options is asking for `scroller_height`. my table is dynamic so i can't tell the table height since i don't know how many rows i have.
I tried to delete the `scroller_height` but there is a default out there.

How can i get the full table rows without vertical scroller and with sticky header?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a sticky header and not the scroller widget.

There are actually two different sticky headers widgets.

1. [stickyHeaders](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sticky-header.html) - uses javascript to position the sticky headers at the top of the page. This widget requires duplicating the `thead` of the table work.
2. [css3StickyHeaders](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-css-sticky-header.html) - uses javascript and css3 transform to position the sticky headers at the top of the page. No duplicate table elements needed.

---

Update: the stickyHeaders widgets are not currently compatible with the scroller widget.

But if you want to make the scroller widget work as you described, make the `scroller_height` some big number, because it only sets the max-height of the tbody. Then add some extra css to hide the scrollbar ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/txLp4xuk/))

CSS

```
.tablesorter-scroller .tablesorter-scroller-table {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Script

```
$(function () {

    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        // widthFixed: true, // <- now automatically set by the scroller widget
        showProcessing: true,
        widgets: ['zebra', 'scroller'],
        widgetOptions: {
            scroller_fixedColumns: 1,
            scroller_height: 3000,
            // scroll tbody to top after sorting
            scroller_upAfterSort: false,
            // pop table header into view while scrolling up the page
            scroller_jumpToHeader: false,
            // In tablesorter v2.19.0 the scroll bar width is auto-detected
            // add a value here to override the auto-detected setting
            scroller_barWidth: null
            // scroll_idPrefix was removed in v2.18.0
            // scroller_idPrefix : 's_'
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Mottie. Actually i want both. sticky header and scroller

Comment: The `scroller_height` option actually sets the max-height, so set it to something like `9999`.

Comment: doesn't work. i set it to 9999 and i can still see a scroller for the last 4-5 rows. the table is not 9999 height ;) and when i vertical scrolling the header is not sticky anymore

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can't combine the two widgets, and the scroller widget will not become a sticky header. Maybe you could have the `scroller_height` set using javascript to match the browser window height (minus the table header & footer).

Comment: on this example the header is not sticky (same in your demo)

Comment: thanks that's better. but is there a way to not have a scroller at all?

Comment: Sure, but you won't get a fixed column then. It would take some fixes to the scroller widget to work the way you describe. I'll see what I can do, but I am really busy with other things and don't have much time for enhancements. I opened a new issue to keep track of it: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/907

Comment: I have been combing the Internet trying to figure out how to do exactly what Mottie did in that fiddle above!  Thanks Mottie!